# Grab lines from a delimited file based on a alphabetical range

Tags: shell, awk, grep

The problem I am working through is that I have a file that will contain fields delimited by a "|" and the file is sorted based on one of those fields.  What I have been trying to come up with is a way to grab lines based on a range of a certain field.

an example:

Sample input would be something like this where it is sorted based on the 2nd field.  So they are listed in alphabetical order

```
1234|abcd|3fgbe32
1234|abce|5fasdf3
5678|abcf|t438fjd
9876|abcg|57fshde
```

The range I want to get would then be "we want all records that fall in the range of abcd - abcf to be recorded into a different file. And the records remaining would be:

```
1234|abcd|3fgbe32
1234|abce|5fasdf33
5678|abcf|t438fjd
```

When I started I think I approached this in the wrong way.  I was looping through each line and then trying to check the line against a regular expression to see if I wanted the line or not.  But would there be a better way of doing this using awk and grep?

Answer (score 3):

> all records that fall in the range of **abcd** - **abcf**

Simple **awk** solution:

```
awk -F'|' '$2~/^abc[d-f]$/' file
```

The output:

```
1234|abcd|3fgbe32
1234|abce|5fasdf3
5678|abcf|t438fjd
```

Answer (score 0):

Another [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution :

```
awk -F'|' '{if ($2 == "abcd") { l=1} else if ($2 == "abcg") { l=0} }l' file
```

Answer (score 0):

A **sed** solution.

To delete the lines before the first in the range:

```
cat file | sed '/abcd/Q'
```

To delete the lines after the last in range:

```
cat file | sed -n '/abcf/,$p'

   -n : don't print non-matches
   ,$ : first match to end of file
   p  : print
```

Putting together:

```
cat file | sed '/abcd/Q | sed -n '/abcf/,$p'
```

The patterns will match any field in the line, so you would need a better pattern to match only the second field:

```
cat file | sed -r -n '/^[^\|]+\|abcd/,$p' | sed -r '/^[^\|]+\|abce/Q'
```

The very simple range using sed would be:

```
cat file | sed -n '/abc[def]/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

records in the range of abcd - abcf using `grep`:

```
grep -E '^[^\|]+\|abc[d-f]\|'
```

Answer (score 0):

All-in-one `sed` solution, writing the range from `abcd` to `abcf` to a file called `other`, while remaining lines are passed to stdout. So you don't have to go through the file twice.

```
sed -e '/|abcd|/,/|abcf|/{wother' -e 'd;}'
```